# How to hide the content of a <td> element in a JSP?

Tags: jsp, hide

I want to prevent a entry to be edited or removed from a table in a JSP. The table is defined as:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center">id</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">description</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">url</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">port</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">username</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">password</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="pojoTable">
        <c:forEach var="pojo" items="${pojoList}" varStatus="loop">
            <tr class="${loop.index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                <td style="text-align: center">${pojo.id}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">${pojo.description}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">${pojo.url}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">${pojo.port}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">${pojo.username}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">${pojo.password}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <c:if test="${pojo.description} ne 'FTP Connection Not Valid'" >
                        <a href="<c:url value="../ftp/edit" />?id=${pojo.id}">
                            <button class="btn">edit</button>
                        </a>
                        <a href="<c:url value="../ftp/remove" />?id=${pojo.id}">
                            <button class="btn">remove</button>
                        </a>
                    </c:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Idea is pretty straight forward. I want the edit and remove buttons not present on the cell actions when description matches 'FTP Connection Not Valid', but only for such line(s).

How to accomplish it? JavaScript?

Comment: Is that a typing mistake? You forgot to  add closing bracket on test attribute in if tag.  test="${pojo.description} ne 'FTP Connection Not Valid'}"

Comment: `<c:if test="${pojo.description} ne 'FTP Connection Not Valid'}" >` still not working. Same result for `<c:if test="{${pojo.description} ne 'FTP Connection Not Valid'}" >`. But, with `<c:if test="${{pojo.description} ne 'FTP Connection Not Valid'}" >` control buttons as shown.

Comment: Oops that should have been   <c:if test="${pojo.description ne 'FTP Connection Not Valid'}" >

Comment: Cool! Working great! Please post as answer so I can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a syntax error. This

```
<c:if test="${pojo.description} ne 'FTP Connection Not Valid'" >
```

should be

```
<c:if test="${pojo.description ne 'FTP Connection Not Valid'}" >
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy! Peace!